# Understanding Error Messages

Tags: solidity

I am trying to figure out what the most gas efficient way to return an error to a user when a transaction reverts is.

The easiest way to do this is with require.

```
function niceFail() public view  returns(string memory) {
    require(false, "Readable message");
    return test;}
```

I have read that what require does is compile into something like this:

```
error Fail(string);
function cheapFail() public view {
    if (false) {
        revert Fail("Readable Message");
    }
}
```

But they don't behave the same way. If I deploy these functions in remix, one will return a message, and the other will not. Obviously, require does more than I have been led to believe. What is the difference?

EDIT: That code was a bad example. Here, consider this contract:

```
contract ErrorTest{
error CustomError(string m);
function revertWithError() public {
    0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4.call{value: 0}("");
    revert CustomError("this is a custom error revert ");
}
function revertWithErrorViewFunction() public view {
    revert CustomError("this is a custom error revert on a view function");
}
function revertWithRequireView() public view {
    require(0==1, "this is a view function revert with require");
}
function revertWithRequire() public {
    0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4.call{value: 0}("");
    require(0 == 1, "this is a state modifying function with a revert with require");
}
```

}

And here, in remix:

[image]

Notice with require, we get the message. With revert Error("message"), we do not.

Comment: If you want to use revert with a message, do ```revert("message")```. I don't know the exact  mechanics, but I believe a raw revert saves a little gas over a require.

Comment: It does, but then you don't actually get the message back ... require is clearly doing something else.

Answer (score 0):

Both `revert Fail("Readable Message");` and `revert("message")` are valid.

I think the main issue is the check condition, the revert is never called:

```
if (false) {
  revert Fail("Readable Message");
}
```

Should use `if(true)` instead. Or just don't use any condition.

Comment: I think maybe this is just a bad example then, I never actually ran this code, let me edit the question

Comment: Please see updated question

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do `if(true) revert("message")` to cause a revert properly. `if(false)` is skipping the revert lines

Comment: Please see updated question